# Vue.js: do not show element until it is in correct position

Tags: html, css, vue.js, user-interface, css-transitions

I am learning Vue and really enjoying it. I have a tab that I want fixed to the bottom of the browser window when the page loads. When a user clicks the tab, it will slide up to show some content.

Everything is working *great*. I am able to have the tab stick to the bottom of the page - and click events are working great as well.

The problem I am having is that I need to calculate the height of tab (and `div`) to set the CSS property correctly. When the page loads, you can see the tab slide down into place. I would like to hide the tab until everything has been calculated and it's in the correct place.

Here is what I'm using:

**app.js**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#info',
    delimiters: ['${', '}'],
    data: {
        active: false,
        inactive: true,
        styles: {
            'bottom': 0
        },
    },
    methods() {
        toggle: function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.active = !this.active;
            this.inactive = !this.inactive;
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        let tabHeight = this.$refs.infoTab.clientHeight;
        let boxHeight = this.$refs.infoBox.clientHeight;  // 473px
    
        this.styles.bottom = -boxHeight + 'px';
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="info not-active" id="info" @click="toggle" ref="infoTab"
     v-cloak
     v-bind:class="{ active: active }"
     v-bind:style="styles">
     <!-- content -->
</div>
```

**style.css**

```
[v-cloak] {
    display: none;
}

/* more classes */

.info {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    &.inactive {
        bottom: -100%;
    }
    &.active {
        bottom: 0 !important;
    }
}
```

I know I am close, I just don't want users to see the tab slide into place. It should just *be* there. I tried using the `created` hook, but `clientHeight` is not available.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve this just using CSS, no need to use any of Vue's lifecycle hooks, I made a pen with a vanilla JS example:

```js
let infoNode = document.getElementById('info');

infoNode.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (infoNode.style.top) {
    // clear inline top style
    infoNode.style.top = '';
  } else {
    // set top to client height + 2 * border thickness
    infoNode.style.top = `calc(100% - ${infoNode.clientHeight}px - 4px)`;
  }
});
```

```css
#info {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid hsl(0, 0%, 80%);
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  /* 100% height of the viewport subtracting:
  tab height: padding, margin, & font size */
  top: calc(100% - (8px + 8px + 24px));
  /* we center the tab horizontally here using
  50% the width of the viewport - 50% the fixed
  width of the tab */
  left: calc(50% - 200px/2);
  transition: top 0.5s;
}

.title {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  display: block;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="info">
  <span class="title">Click on Me</span>
  <p>
    This is the content of the tab, isn't it great? I think so too, and it can be of any arbitrary length!
  </p>
</div>
```

Basically the trick is to use `calc` with `top` instead of `-100%` with `bottom` for your positioning, then your tab is initially rendered in the correct position and you don't have to worry it being out of place when a visitor first loads your page.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had such tunnel vision learning some new tech and didn't think to get out of my own way.